# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection' while training objects images

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

I downloaded Tensorflow object_detection API. I was  able to run the tutorial and see the results (Everything went well I followed this video: [TensorFlow Object Detection API Tutorial p.1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COlbP62-B-U)).

When I tried to train my own object I got this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'
```

while running this command:

```
python3 generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=data/train_labels.csv  --output_path=data/train.record
```

**Note:** I ran all these commands but did not work

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim

sudo python3 setup.py build

sudo python3 setup.py install

sudo pip install -e .
```

Info:

I am using Ubuntu 18, Tensorflow 1.8.0

Comment: You're using `pip` not `pip3`. Also looks like you're installing as root, but running as your standard user account which, from personal experience on Ubuntu, I have had cause issues with Python path modules

Comment: Thank you so much man!!! You were right. I ran the same command as a super user and it worked.